# How to place text above the figure/table

Tags: tables

How to place text above the rotated Figure (LANDSCAPE) in the same page. I tried but text automatically moved to the following page.

```
TEXT TEXT....


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=160mm]{figures2/comparation3.png}
\caption{A comparison of Aloha protocols}
\label{tab:ComparationAloha}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

---

I added this code, but one part of table disappeared. I must have type TABLE since I need it for list of tables later.

```
\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[h!]
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{100mm}{
\includegraphics[width=160mm, rotate=90]{figures2/comparation3.png}
\caption{A comparison of Aloha protocols}
\label{tab:ComparationAloha}}}
\end{table}
\lipsum[12]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want the whole environment to be rotated (including the caption)?

Comment: @Bernard I want to rotate only figure/table

Comment: Together with caption

Comment: Note that if  the rotated image is to have a height of 160 mm and has a caption there remains not much space for text…

Comment: I have few sentences, or maybe I will reduce the size of image

Comment: @Bernard do you have a solution?

Comment: @Bernard, the whole text now has frame. It is not ok

Comment: It is just the frame option of `geometry` that I use to check nothing flows into the margin. Remove this option, it is not made for final versions.

Comment: @Bernard now its working :) One more question, what is if I want to rotate caption? Thank you

Comment: The code will be different, because in this case, you can't use the figure environment anymore. Please see my updated answer

Comment: @Bernard please see new issue.

Comment: @Bernard please see my last comment bellow

Comment: Which last comment?

Comment: @Bernard Last post with code. down

Comment: Use `\label{tab:ComparationThree}}}` with three closing braces, not one.

Comment: @Bernard now is ok but I have text that I did not added and cannot find it in code but in pdf exists.

"Sed feugiat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
mus. Ut pellentesque augue sed urna. Vestibulum diam eros, fringilla et, consectetuer eu, nonummy
..."

Comment: @Bernard now I saw. It appears just when I used your code? Three times on three figures

Comment: One simply has to close every opening brace by a corresponding closing brace. I think my code was correct as I tested it before posting, but there may be copy-paste accidents…

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with package `adjustbox` (needless to load `graphicx` in this case – this package does it for you):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox, rotating} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\adjincludegraphics[width = 150mm, rotate = 90]{Piero_di_Cosimo_2}
\caption{A comparison of Aloha protocols}
\label{tab:ComparationAloha}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to rotate both the graphic file and its caption, you can use this code:

```
\lipsum[11]
\begin{center}
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{100mm}{
    \includegraphics[width = 100mm]{Piero_di_Cosimo₂}
    \captionof{figure}{A comparison of Aloha protocols}
    \label{tab:ComparationAloha}}}
 \end{center}
 \lipsum[12]
```

[image]