# Rotating image with caption but to place text below

Tags: captions

I wanted to rotate image with caption. It was good, but also I want to keep my text below. It doesn't work:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\adjincludegraphics[width=150mm]{figures2/comparation1.png}
\caption{A comparison of Aloha, tree-based and hybrid protocols}
\label{tab:ComparationAll}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: why did you tag this biblatex pdftex and latex3?

Comment: your question isn't very clear but perhaps remove the landscape  environment and use `\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics....}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it doesn't work. After your code, table dissapeared

Comment: It can't work with `landscape` which creates a new page for its contents

Comment: @John988 it will work (it is my code, `landscape`, environment, `\rotatebox` and `\includegraphics` all come from packages with my name on:-) You have provided no test document so impossible to guess what you have done wrong. Make a small _complete_ document (you can use the image `example-image` which is available for such examples)

Comment: What is the difference between this question and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428176/how-to-place-text-above-the-figure-table ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, could you share me your code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean I have already shared the code I have (you have the lscape and graphicx packages) you are asking about something not working so you need to provide an example document in your question, it is impossible to debug code that you can not see,

Comment: \begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
 \rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[width=150mm] 
       {figures2/comparation1.png}}
 \caption{A comparison of Aloha, tree-based and hybrid 
         protocols}
 \label{tab:ComparationAll}
        \end{table}

@DavidCarlisle Caption did not rotate?

Comment: well obviously not, but I assumed that's what you wanted perhaps you want to put the caption in a minipage and put the minipage in another \rotatebox it is hard to guess, but don't just put code fragments on comments make a proper test document that can be debugged. unrelated don't use `[!h]`  normally latex will warn you it is changing it to `[!ht]` but as written it means not top not bottom and not on a page of tables, so it gives latex almost nowhere to put the table so it makes it very likely to go to the end of the document

Comment: I pasted all. It is one of my latex files. Everything is ok but caption did not rotated 90 degree